# Is it safer to load decryption keys in a PHP file from another php file which is set to only accept connections from localhost?

Tags: php, mysql, security, web

I'm not handling a zillion userpasswords in an unencrypted form, don't worry :)

I'm not particularly good at PHP, this is a server-side component of a script I wrote which will receive encrypted calls, decrypt them, and store them in a mysql database. I was wondering if it's safer to "hide" the decryption keys in a file which is inaccessible to the outside world under any circumstances?

Is there a smarter way to go about this? Or it doesn't matter at all?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Security always matters :)

Yes, definitely storing them outside the accessible web space is a must.

Comment: how do I set privileges such that a calling php page has access to another php page which stores the keys? Should I use chmod for that or .htaccess?

Comment: well that strongly depends on the server config, can't really tell you that... but you propably would need the open_base_dir directive allowed... however - not sure what you mean by "another php page" - this will not work between distant servers - you did not mention it were distant servers...

Comment: @dps_099 - you should upvote/accept the answer if it was useful to you :)

Comment: @dps_099 - thanx... yea, noticed the downvote, I would be interested in the explanation for it :)

Answer (score 1):

Safer than using MySQL, or safer than keeping them in a plaintext file in general?

MySQL would be the preferred approach (encrypted with MD5).  http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php

But if you're comparing against simply putting in a plain text file the approach you mentioned is preferred over that.  Typically you would locate the login file in a completely separate location inaccessible to a user (but accessible to the PHP user), such as at a higher folder level.

However, I would recommend using the MD5 function in PHP (which can be salted) and not the one built in to MySQL: http://alan.blog-city.com/cracking_mysqls_md5_function__within_seconds.htm

Reference: MySQL encryption functions http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html

Comment: well, he's talking about DECRYPTION KEYS - I suppose in a manner like AES uses or what.... you can't make them `md5()` hashed.... pay more attention to the question ;)

Comment: Michal is right, I don't want to encrypt decryption keys, that will get crazy.

Comment: @dsp_099 Yes, certainly not.  I'd misread that portion of your question.  However I think the crux of my answer still stands -- the database would be considered the safer spot.  But if you were going to store them in the file system, at least move to a spot inaccessible from the web user.

Comment: @msigman - what sense does that make? if you store them in a DB then you have to care about the DB access data instead... AND storing them in a DB makes it not safer since the DB would be one of the primary attack targets when it comes to compromising. not to mention bobby tables etc...